# wp-login.php Flood in Acces Logs

Tags: wordpress, apache, server, brute-force, access-log

I noticed that in my access logs these records are flooding. I'm not sure is this a brute force attack because the IP address is my server's IP.

How can I figure what's going on?

```
185.124.86.73 - - [27/Dec/2016:06:39:04 +0300] "POST /wp-login.php HTTP/1.0" 500 - "-" "-"
185.124.86.73 - - [27/Dec/2016:06:39:04 +0300] "POST /wp-login.php HTTP/1.0" 500 - "-" "-"
185.124.86.73 - - [27/Dec/2016:06:39:04 +0300] "POST /wp-login.php HTTP/1.0" 500 - "-" "-"
185.124.86.73 - - [27/Dec/2016:06:39:04 +0300] "POST /wp-login.php HTTP/1.0" 500 - "-" "-"
185.124.86.73 - - [27/Dec/2016:06:39:04 +0300] "POST /wp-login.php HTTP/1.0" 500 - "-" "-"
185.124.86.73 - - [27/Dec/2016:06:39:04 +0300] "POST /wp-login.php HTTP/1.0" 500 - "-" "-"
185.124.86.73 - - [27/Dec/2016:06:39:05 +0300] "POST /wp-login.php HTTP/1.0" 500 - "-" "-"
185.124.86.73 - - [27/Dec/2016:06:39:05 +0300] "POST /wp-login.php HTTP/1.0" 500 - "-" "-"
185.124.86.73 - - [27/Dec/2016:06:39:05 +0300] "POST /wp-login.php HTTP/1.0" 500 - "-" "-"
185.124.86.73 - - [27/Dec/2016:06:39:05 +0300] "POST /wp-login.php HTTP/1.0" 500 - "-" "-"
185.124.86.73 - - [27/Dec/2016:06:39:05 +0300] "POST /wp-login.php HTTP/1.0" 500 - "-" "-"
```

Comment: Can you please check this url: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/i-ve-been-flooded-with-post-requests-at-wp-login-php, https://www.icontrolwp.com/blog/beware-new-security-theat-wordpress-misinformation-virus/?cid=1500

Comment: I've already checked it, but the IP's are outside in that question. But I'm seeing accesses from my server IP and I have no idea how to investigate it.

Answer (score 1):

The Solution was to Create a mod_security rule to block such offending IP address.

1. Create  file name “wpbrute.conf”  in /usr/local/apache/conf/modsec_rules and add following to it.

> SecRule REQUEST_LINE "POST .*wp-login.*"
>   "pass,initcol:ip=%{REMOTE_ADDR},setvar:ip.maxlimit=+1,deprecatevar:ip.maxlimit=1/600,nolog,id:35011"
>   SecRule IP:MAXLIMIT "@gt 10" "log,deny,id:350111,msg:'wp-bruteforce:
>   denying %{REMOTE_ADDR} (%{ip.maxlimit} connection attempts)'"

2. Open file /usr/local/apache/conf/modsec2.user.conf and add include path as below and save the file.

> Include /usr/local/apache/conf/modsec_rules/wpbrute.conf

**Now all the attacked to the “wp-login.php” should be stopped**

Comment: @Oral ÜNAL you see answer?

Comment: Yeap, I was trying to log varnish access logs. Because of varnish I was seeing the Server IP on apache access logs.